# Python y funciones. Cuando corre el programa muestra el siguiente error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable en la función cambiar_orden_texto

Tags: python, funciones, parametros, typeerror

Estoy iniciando en Python y me encuentro practicando el módulo de funciones. En resumen, el programa está escrito para que reciba una frase de un usuario desde la consola (Terminal) `frase = input("Escriba la frase: ")`, luego, llame **la primera función** `def quitar_espacio(texto):` y retorne la frase escrita sin espacios `return texto_sin_espacios`. Ahora, **la segunda función** `def cambiar_orden_texto(quitar_espacio):` debe tomar la frase escrita sin los espacios y rescribirla al revés. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuté la sentencia `texto1 = quitar_espacio(frase)` se presentó en la consola (Terminal), **el error**: *TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*. Me podrían explicar ¿Cuáles son los problemas y como se pueden resolver? Mil gracias.

```
#El usuario introduce una frase: El programa elimina los espacios y muestra la frase al revés.
#Elimanará los espacios de la frase
def quitar_espacio(texto): 

    pos_indice = -1
    texto_sin_espacios = ""

    for indice in texto:
        if indice != " ":
            pos_indice = pos_indice+1
            texto_sin_espacios += indice
    return texto_sin_espacios

#Cambiará el orden de la frase sin espacios
#Inclusión de la función quitar_espacio con sus argumentos

def cambiar_orden_texto(quitar_espacio): 
    texto1 = quitar_espacio(frase)
    texto1 = str(texto1)
    Cambio_orden = ""  # Nuevo vector donde se almacenará texto1 al revés

    for indice1 in texto1:
        Cambio_orden = indice1+Cambio_orden
    return cambiar_orden_texto

#(Entradas)
frase = input("Escriba la frase: ")
#Funcion y argumentos
quitar_espacio(frase)
#Salida
print("La frase sin espacio es: ", quitar_espacio(frase))

#(Entradas) Esta función no tiene ingresos adicionales por el usuarios.
#Funcion y argumentos
cambiar_orden_texto(quitar espacio(frase))
# Salida
print("La frase alreves es: ", cambiar_orden_texto(frase))
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes.
Creas **pos_indice = -1** y luego **pos_indice = pos_indice +1**, que nuca usas.

```
def cambiar_orden_texto( quitar_espacio ):
```

Mal, no recibe una función como parámetro, sino una cadena, osea:

```
def cambiar_orden_texto( cadena ):
```

Luego viene:

```
texto1 = quitar_espacio( frase )
texto1 = str( texto1 )
```

La linea **texto1 = str( texto1 )** es un sin sentido, **quitar_espacio** devuelve una cadena.

```
 Cambio_orden = ""
```

Bien, aunque no es un vector, es una cadena.

```
return cambiar_orden_texto
```

En vez de devolver la cadena invertida, devuelves la función, debería ser:

```
return Cambio_orden
```

Vamos con los llamados a las funciones.
Te has hecho un lio, digno de película (no te sientas solo, nos pasa a todos).

Después de pedir la entrada, llamas a **quitar_espacio**, pero no asignas el retorno a ninguna variable, no es que este mal, ya que **frase**, es modificada, que es el objetivo de la función (solo que no puedes "ver" el resultado), luego haces un **print( quitar_espacio( frase ))**, osea, llamas a **quitar_espacio** con una cadena que no tiene espacios...
Después tenemos una linea interesante:

```
cambiar_orden_texto( quitar espacio( frase ))
```

Me gusta, le pasas a **quitar espacio** (se te olvido poner el **_**), pasandole **frase** como parámetro y a **cambiar_orden_texto** pasandole como parámetro lo que devuelve **quitar_espacio**... pero estamos en lo mismo que antes,esta sería la tercera vez que llamas a **quitar_espacio**, y por si fuera poco, vuelves a no asignar a ninguna variable lo que se devuelve.
Ahora bien, si uso esa linea, no tiene sentido que dentro de **cambiar_orden_texto** invoques a **quitar_espacio**, (sería la función más llamada de la historia).

Por último, te quedo sin imprimir el resultado, y usas un:

```
print( "La frase al revés es: ", cambiar_orden_texto( frase ))
```

que está bien... o no, depende de lo que quieras hacer.
Yo dejaría tu código así:

```
def quitar_espacio( texto ): 
    texto_sin_espacios = ""
    for indice in texto:
        if indice != " ":
            texto_sin_espacios += indice
    return texto_sin_espacios

def cambiar_orden_texto( frase ): 
    Cambio_orden = ""  
    for indice1 in texto1:
        Cambio_orden = indice1+Cambio_orden
        
    return Cambio_orden

frase = input("Escriba la frase: ")

print( f"La frase alreves es: {cambiar_orden_texto( quitar_espacio( frase ))}")
```

Aunque también podrías usar:

```
def quitar_espacio(texto): 

      # replaceAll recibe dos parámetros (cadenas), y reemplaza cada aparición 
      # de la primera, con la segunda
    return texto.replaceAll( " ", "" )

def cambiar_orden_texto( frase ):            
    return frase[::-1]

frase = input("Escriba la frase: ")

print( f"La frase al revés es: {cambiar_orden_texto( quitar_espacio( frase ))}")
```

O podemos reemplazar el print por:

```
fraseSinEspacios = quitar_espacio( frase )
print( f"La frase sin espacios es: {fraseSinEspacios}" )
print( f"La frase al revés es: {cambiar_orden_texto( fraseSinEspacios )}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas que yo veo son:

1. `pos_indice` nunca lo usas.

```
pos_indice = -1
```

2. Aquí mandas una función como argumento pero nunca mandas la frase.

```
def cambiar_orden_texto(quitar_espacio)
```

3. Acá `Cambio_orden` no es un vector, es un `string`, y las variables no llevan mayúsculas en Python. Según tengo entendido lo más cercano a un vector son listas, o al menos que uses NumPy donde se pueden crear vectores.

```
 Cambio_orden = ""  # Nuevo vector donde se almacenará texto1 al revés
```

4. Aquí cambias el orden del texto pero ¿regresas la función?

```
for indice1 in texto1:
    Cambio_orden = indice1+Cambio_orden
return cambiar_orden_texto
```

5. Acá te falta guión bajo.

```
cambiar_orden_texto(quitar espacio(frase))
```

Empieza por descargar un editor de código como VS Code para que te muestre los errores.

El código corregido queda así:

```
def quitar_espacio(texto):
    texto_modificado = ""
    for i in texto:
        if i != " ":
            texto_modificado += i
    return texto_modificado


def cambiar_orden(frase):
    texto = quitar_espacio(frase)
    cambio_orden = ""

    for i in texto:
        cambio_orden = i + cambio_orden
    return cambio_orden


frase = input("Frase: ")

print("Frase sin espacio: ", quitar_espacio(frase))
print("Frase invertida: ", cambiar_orden(frase))
```

Todavía necesitas agregar la validación para que no se ejecute si no se ingresa nada y que solamente acepte letras.